# Ajax success leaks into other selector

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

http://tinyns.com/wtf.php

I'm using jQuery Typist to display server benchmarks results. I have the results saved in a database and they're called via ajax from ajax.php.

The problem is, is that the results are 'typed' into each other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript"></script>
    <script src=
    "https://raw.github.com/davidcrawford/typist-jquery/master/jquery.typist.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php?who=theirs",
    async: false,
    success: function(q) {
        $('#opp').typist({
            height: 75
        });
         $('#whoa').typist('prompt')
        .typist('type', 'dd if=' + q['if'] + ' of=/home/output.img bs=' + q['bs'] + 'k count=' + q['count'] + 'k')
        .typist('wait', 2000)
        .typist('speed', 'fast')
        .typist('echo', q['recordsIn'] + ' records in')
        .typist('echo', q['recordsOut'] + ' records in')
        .typist('echo', q['bytesCopied'] + ' bytes (' + q['mathMegs'] + ' MB) copied, ' + q['time'] + ' s, ' + q['speed'] + ' MB/s');    
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php?who=us",
    async: false,
    success: function(q) {
        $('#whoa').typist({
            height: 75
        });
        $('#whoa').typist('prompt')
        .typist('type', 'dd if=' + q['if'] + ' of=/home/output.img bs=' + q['bs'] + 'k count=' + q['count'] + 'k')
        .typist('wait', 2000)
        .typist('speed', 'fast')
        .typist('echo', q['recordsIn'] + ' records in')
        .typist('echo', q['recordsOut'] + ' records in')
        .typist('echo', q['bytesCopied'] + ' bytes (' + q['mathMegs'] + ' MB) copied, ' + q['time'] + ' s, ' + q['speed'] + ' MB/s');
    }
});
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="doTests" name="doTests">#doTests</a>

    <h1>#opp</h1><br>
    <br>

    <div id="opp" style="font-size:15px;"></div><br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <h1>#whoa</h1><br>
    <br>

    <div id="whoa" style="font-size:15px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post the relevant codes plz!!

Comment: no idea what the problem is or what you are  asking.

Comment: Added, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/davidcrawford/typist-jquery/issues/2

Seems like the typist plugin does not support more than one call in one page.